# Round a number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very simple problem. I want to break an interval from `1e-6` to `10e-6` into ten values and append them to a list. For this reason, I made the program below,

```
start_value = 1e-6
stop_value = 10e-6
step_value = 10
step = (stop_value-start_value)/(step_value-9)

current_list = [start_value]
last_value = start_value

for i in range(step_value-1):
    current_list.append(last_value + step)
    last_value = last_value + step

print(current_list)
```

I get the following result,

```
[1e-06, 2e-06, 3e-06, 4e-06, 4.9999999999999996e-06, 5.999999999999999e-06, 6.999999999999999e-06, 8e-06, 9e-06, 1e-05].
```

Of course, the numbers `4.999999999e-6` and `6.999999999e-6` should be  `5e-06` and `7e-06` respectively. For this purpose I used the `round(**number** ,11)` method.

```
start_value = 1e-6
stop_value = 10e-6
step_value = 10
step = (stop_value-start_value)/(step_value-9)

current_list = [start_value]
last_value = start_value

for i in range(step_value-1):
    current_list.append(round(last_value + step, 11))
    last_value = last_value + step

print(current_list)
```

Is there another way to make this?

Comment: `[round(1e-6 * i, 11) for i in range(1, 11)]`? Or `np.linspace(1e-6, 10e-6, 10)`? Despite what Python wants you to think, TIMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(1,11,1)*1e-6
```

output:

```
array([1.e-06, 2.e-06, 3.e-06, 4.e-06, 5.e-06, 6.e-06, 7.e-06, 8.e-06,
   9.e-06, 1.e-05])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the `fractions` module:

```
import fractions


start_value = fractions.Fraction(1, 1000000)
stop_value = fractions.Fraction(10, 1000000)
step_value = 10
step = fractions.Fraction(stop_value-start_value, (step_value - 1))

current_list = []

for i in range(step_value):
    current_list.append(start_value + i * step)
```

The default output maintains a list of `Fraction` types:

```
print(current_list)

[Fraction(1, 1000000), Fraction(1, 500000), Fraction(3, 1000000), Fraction(1, 250000), Fraction(1, 200000), Fraction(3, 500000), Fraction(7, 1000000), Fraction(1, 125000), Fraction(9, 1000000), Fraction(1, 100000)]
```

But it's simple enough to cast to native data types:

```
print([float(x) for x in current_list])

[1e-06, 2e-06, 3e-06, 4e-06, 5e-06, 6e-06, 7e-06, 8e-06, 9e-06, 1e-05]
```